# Group by +- margin using python

Tags: python, pandas

Group by +- margin using python
I want to group my dataframe composed of 2 columns ['1', '2'] based on a margin +-1 (1) and +-10 (2) for example [[273, 10],[274, 14],[275, 15]] I want it to result into [[273, 10],[274, 14]],[[274, 14],[275, 15]].

But I have a pretty big dataset, group by method does not solve the problem since I can not enter both conditions.

This kind of code for example take me for ever, with no resuls

```
1 = np.random.uniform(low=300, high=1800, size=(300000,))
2 = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=7200, size=(300000,))
print("Random numbers were created")
df = pd.DataFrame({'1': 1, '2':2})
df['id'] = df.index
1_MARGIN = 1
2_MARGIN = 10

tic = time.time()

group = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    
    filtered_df = df[(row['1'] - 1_MARGIN < df['1']) & (df['1'] < row['1'] + 1_MARGIN) & 
                     (row['2'] - 2_MARGIN < df['2']) & (df['2'] < row['2'] + 2_MARGIN)]
    group.append(filtered_df[['id', '1']].values.tolist())

toc = time.time()
print(f"for loop: {str(1000*(toc-tic))} ms")
```

I also tried

```
data = df.groupby('1')['2'].apply(list).reset_index(name='irt')
```

I got the results that I want but I can't work with the conditions

Comment: Would you please edit the question and place the expected output with also the current output.

Comment: what do u mean ?

Comment: When you run your script what's the output? Even if it's the wrong answer, i.e. the one you don't want, it's nice to have it anyway in the question itself so other users can analyse it without the need to figure out what's requirements, copy the code, and then run.

Comment: yeah that's the problem it just run for ever with no output

Comment: Oh, I see now. Well, testing it on my local machine takes forever indeed to finish. Actually, it's processing but it's pretty slow. You can check the progress if you add `    if index % 1000 == 0: print(index)` in the middle of the `for` loop. It's lie 1000 rows per second. And having 300,000 rows would give us 5 minutes on my machine.

Comment: no I just put some random data, but my real data in more complex meaning more than 1 million data point 125.2315215461 like this values so the code is not working at all

Comment: I see. You should make it clear then that you want specifically to optimize the algorithm for `group by +- margin` in Pandas. Explain that at the current state it takes 1 second per 1000 rows and you have millions of rows to process and it would take at least half an hour to process. The title could be something along the lines of `How to optimize Pandas group by +- margin`. All of this so you can reach potential answers easily. It's like SEO for Stack Overflow. :)

Comment: Also, have you considered running this on Hadoop/Spark on a cluster? Maybe this is a job for it as you have too much data to process on a single machine.